# HTML bootstrap add option to input form

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

Im using a form to be able to use the input of the user to save some information.

In this case it's instructions for a receipt. However I would like to have an unlimited number of fields for that (as you can see in the image it has 3 fields).

I would like to have an option at the bottom, like a button where it would create a new input field. I've searched in bootstrap documentation and I don't find anything related to that, they always use a fixed number of input fields...
Any suggestion?

This is the code I'm using to generate the fields (10 at the moment):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Instructions</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
            <table style="width:75%">
                <tr>
                    <th><label asp-for="Instructions[0].Designation" class="control-label"></label></th>
                </tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input asp-for="Instructions[i].Designation" class="form-control" placeholder="Step @(i+1) " /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Instructions[i].Designation" class="text-danger"></span>

                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: If I where you I would create a button that adds a new input field every time the user pushes the button. For the task you can use jQuery.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is out of Bootstrap's scope. Namely, it doesn't have any methods to create markup for you. It's aimed at helping you style up whatever markup you have. Therefore, you have to research creating elements on the fly, giving them classes and appending them to DOM. Chances are you're already importing jQuery, which makes it easy to modify DOM. If not, you can use vanilla JavaScript. Whichever way, you have to write an attempt at this task yourself and ask about any issues you might run into. Without an attempt, your question is *off-topic* on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a fully functional example on how you can achive what you are asking for:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Instructions</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Instructions</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <table id="instructionsTable" style="width:75%">
            <tr>
                <th><label asp-for="Instructions[0].Designation" class="control-label"></label></th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input asp-for="Instructions[i].Designation" class="form-control" placeholder="Step @(i+1)" /></td>
                </tr>
                <span asp-validation-for="Instructions[i].Designation" class="text-danger"></span>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input id="addInputBtn" type="button" value="+" />

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addInputBtn").click(function(){
            var newInput = "<tr><td><input asp-for='Instructions[i].Designation' class='form-control' placeholder='' /></td></tr>";
            $("#instructionsTable").append(newInput);
        })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```